# Play Multiple online videos in FFMPEG

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm trying to make an Android Applicaion that uses FFMPEG to play online streams. I gone through dolphin player source and with the help of this i achieved playing udp streams in android. Now i am trying to play multiple streams in my player. For example i have a list activity that has 10 names and by clicking each name the corrosponding video should be played. How can i achieve this in avformat_open_input. I am very new to ffmpeg. Please help me in achiving this. Thanks in advance.

My c code is as follows:

```
static int decode_module_init(void *arg) 
{
    VideoState *is = (VideoState *)arg;
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;

    int err;
    int ret = -1;

    int i;

    int video_index = -1;
    int audio_index = -1;


    is->videoStream=-1;
    is->audioStream=-1;

    char* Filename = "udp://.....";

    global_video_state = is;

    pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
    pFormatCtx->interrupt_callback.callback = decode_interrupt_cb;
    pFormatCtx->interrupt_callback.opaque = is;


    **err = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, Filename , NULL, NULL);**

    if (err < 0) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "message", "File open failed");
        ret = -1;
        goto decode_module_init_fail;

    }

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "message", "File open successful");
}
```

Comment: Could you paste the entire code? Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve the problem?